# Advantage of using Spring roo over play framework (if we use Spring framework)?

Tags: spring, playframework, spring-roo

I recently stumbled upon Play framework while evaluating frameworks to use in a project.
I need to use Java language and JVM (so grails is not an option).

From initial impression Play framework looks very similar to Django (or Rails), but Spring Roo looks interesting because I use Spring framework for core components.

Is there any advantage of using Spring Roo if i already use core Spring framework (say for e.g. integration)?

Is there any known major issues with Spring Roo? (e.g. like losing control over code as it generates for us)

Comment: @NimChimpsky True, but the problem is we cannot use groovy.

Comment: Play framwork doesn't involve Spring, that's the biggest advantge ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my private impression, so it might be (very) subjective. I'm also a *Play* advocate.

I was enforced to give `Spring MVC` a try... That was some kind of %$%@$%#... uncomfortable to me, having to worry about XML files...

So I found `Roo` which can scaffold apps quite nice (especially compared to Spring) I thought that it's sensible to use it, however it also takes too much effort to keep an eye on all depended files while your project is growing (I don't know, maybe wrong IDE, maybe not too much patience...) After a week I was ready to go back to PHP, forever ;)

Finally I found Play and that's the point for me, I don't need to deal no more with XML 'support' which driven me crazy. Common structure is much cleaner than in Spring-*. I don't need to care about configuring [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) or redeploying the app. Everything works just from the first step. Only thing I need to do is to... develop!

So, concluding I think that you *should* give Play a chance, maybe it will be a better choice than celebrating uncomfortable habits. Maybe. You have to choose yourself.

BTW: both are really different approaches, you won't judge it correctly without solid comparison of both solutions with the same topic.

Comment: I personally think Roo is just as easy as Play. Take this for example:  http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#intro-first-steps

Comment: _I was enforced to give the Spring MVC a try... That was some kind of %$%@$%#.... uncomfortable to me to still get worrying about the XML files ..._ - you are obviously not talking about modern Spring MVC as it can be configured with 0 xml, all pure java, not even a web.xml

Comment: @ike_love - yes, that was a quite long ago and as I started: that's my very subjective opinion ;)

Answer (score 11):

It all depends on what kind of application you are developing.  If you want to have a simple application with a few controllers, I am sure Play is a good candidate.  However if you are writing a large scale enterprise application and want to take advantage of all that Spring has to offer, Roo is the way to go.  Spring is the de facto enterprise Java framework, every software vendor makes sure to provide Spring integration, for example it takes one line of XML to launch a SOAP web service:

```
<jaxws:endpoint implementor="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.service.Hello" address="http://localhost:8080/test" />
```

Want to connect to a RabbitMQ

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/>
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

But that is just core Spring, Roo makes things even simpler, want to add a database? Type one line in Roo's command shell.  Security?  One more line.  Launch to Cloud Foundry?  One more line.  The auto-suggest features will tell you all the command available and parameters required for each one.  The BIGGEST advantage of Roo (for a seasoned Spring developer) is not having to learn any new frameworks, you just type Roo commands and get standard Spring code that you can then do whatever you want with.  If you feel more comfortable with plain Spring, you can use Roo to jump start your project and then remove it.  I am not one to jump on latest technology bandwagons, pretty skeptical when it comes to "this will improve your life!" promises, but Roo really does make development simpler and quicker.

Answer (score 9):

From what I have seen previously, a big difference between Roo and Play is that Roo creates boilerplate code for you, that you then maintain, whereas Play simply reduces the amount of code you need to develop, and therefore, reduces the amount of code you need to maintain.

If you were starting from zero, I don't see the benefit of Roo over Play (personal opinion as a Play advocate). However, as you already come from a Spring background, then Roo may be a better choice as there is no learning curve for you (and depending on which version of Play you are thinking about, this could be a factor).

Comment: The learning curve for Play 1.x is very flat. 2.x is more flexible and will bring up the question of Scala or not. @Codemwnci is right, the play version you choose is a factor to take into account

Answer (score -3):

I don't know the [Spring Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/spring), but I've been trying to use Spring Roo 1.2.3 by following the ["Getting started with Roo" pdf](http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/Getting_Started_with_Roo.pdf&ei=-xs1UYbwA8XBqAGf6IHQDA&usg=AFQjCNE092ZIBX-2uPnwhSWL2ley3PKECg&bvm=bv.43148975,d.aWM) and the experience has been quite disappointing. It does not work, there is no workaround and no support for the known problems in the internet. Download the guide that I mentioned before and try to use it step by step: you will see what I'm talking about. As for your question: choose the framework which at least is not broken or abandoned. Spring Roo makes a lot of promises, but when you spend several days trying to make it work, without success, you start to question yourself: where is the advantage I'm getting? Don't get me wrong, I would love to use Spring Roo, but it has been quite impossible to do so.

Comment: Please add concrete problems you've run into that would answer the OP's particular questions as to whether this is worth using.